# Does spring 3.x support @JmsListener or @RabbitListener annotation?

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, jms

I am using spring 3.x and trying to integrate JMS or rabbitmq with my project. I saw rabbitmq does not support @RabbitListener annotation on spring 3.x, it supports from spring 4.x . So as an alternative I am trying to implement jms with @JmsListener annotation but not able to get it working. So I am looking for any reference or something that should clarify whether it will be supported on spring 3.x or not

Comment: Spring 3.x way too old, I don't think it's gonna be supported there.

Comment: Is there any breaking changes between 3.x and 4.x of spring?\